# How to fix selenium not opening browser in server when called from another script?

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess

I want to open selenium browser on a button click from a specific site. I'm using `flask` server.
So from an endpoint, I call selenium script using `subprocess`.

**server.py**

```
import subprocess

args = [PYTHON_PATH, SCRIPT_PATH]
subprocess.Popen(args,
                 cwd="/",
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                 start_new_session=True)
```

Here is the script that opens browser.

**script.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

print("Starting Browser")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chromeOptions)
print("Browser opened")
```

When `script.py` is opened from shell, it works correctly. But when called as subprocess from `server.py`, it stops at `Starting Browser`.
No Error message is shown. Browser is not launched.
How do I fix this?

Comment: is the path `executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` setup correctly on server ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes. that's why it works from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0`. And update `PATH` variable.

```py
import subprocess

// These two lines
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0' 
os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

args = [PYTHON_PATH, SCRIPT_PATH]
subprocess.Popen(args,
                 cwd="/",
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                 start_new_session=True)
```

This  solved the issue.

Same solution applies for those running script via `cronjob`.
Set these environment variables **inside** **crontab** file before calling script.